# static const struct member

Tags: c, struct

I am setting up a structure for Modbus RTU communication, but i got problems writing the apropriate structure. Here is the structure i got up to now:

```
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct TModbusFrameRtu_tag
{
  static const uint32_t  Start : 28;
  uint8_t         Address;
  uint8_t         Function;
  uint8_t         Data;
  uint16_t        Crc16;
  static const uint32_t  End : 28;
}TModbusFrameRtu;

const uint32_t TModbusFrameRtu_tag::Start = 0x0000;
const uint32_t TModbusFrameRtu_tag::End   = 0x0000;
```

But the compiler doesnt like the `static const` combination. Trying to compile this code the compiler prints

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'static'|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token|
error: expected identifier before numeric constant|
error: unknown type name 'TModbusFrameRtu'|
```

I thought i could save some space by declaring the Start and End member static, as they are always going to be the same and will never change for any message that is going to be send. Is this not possible in that combination or how can i solve this?

Comment: No, that construct doesn't exist in C.

Comment: But also, think about what you're trying to do.  If you're defining these as bitfields, what would it mean to "share" these fields between separate instances?

Comment: With respect to `uint32_t  End : 28;` do you know *which* 28 bits are being used?

Comment: @ Andrew Henle: No, i dont. The values are going to be initialiezed to zero and starting from that point it does not matter, which bits are going to be used as i see it, but that is a good remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

It doesn't make sense, the members of a struct need to be together in memory, but you somehow want to "pull out" a couple of fields and have them live elsewhere.

Would you expect e.g.

```
TModbusFrameRtu frame_a, frame_b; // two instances
```

to have the same value for `&frame_a.Start` and `&frame_b.Start`? That's not how things work, at all.

The solution is probably to not include these in the structure at all, but instead make them ordinary constants inside the implementation.

Comment: that totally makes sense :D. You are right, i am going to implement it in the transfer protocoll instead of the struct. Thanks!